# Serve Base64 GIF in Nginx

Tags: nginx

Is it possible to serve a base64 image (GIF) in Nginx that will load in the browser? The encoded string below is a 1x1 white pixel GIF.

I tried this, which isn't working

```
location /img.gif {
  default_type "image/gif;base64";
  return 200 "R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///wAAACwAAAAAAQABAAACAkQBADs=";
}
```

That image loads fine with

```
<img width="64" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///wAAACwAAAAAAQABAAACAkQBADs=">
```

Comment: I don't know an answer to your question, but do you aware about the [`ngx_http_empty_gif_module`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_empty_gif_module.html)?

Comment: Additionally, you can use [`set_decode_base64`](https://github.com/openresty/set-misc-nginx-module#set_decode_base64) directive from the 3rd party [`set-misc-nginx-module`](https://github.com/openresty/set-misc-nginx-module) to serve any binary data via nginx cofig: `location /img.gif { set_decode_base64 $gif "R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///wAAACwAAAAAAQABAAACAkQBADs="; return 200 $gif; }`. This module is also included into the [OpenResty](https://openresty.org/en/) bundle.

Answer (score 2):

I have tested a njs approach as you are very flexible with this solution. However - I am not understanding the use case to a 100% but if this is the only solution because you are maybe getting the image bytes b64  encoded from another service on the fly and unable to store them as a file that could be the way to go.

First load the NGINX njs module `load_module modules/ngx_http_js_module.so;`

### Create your NJS file

```
export default {b64d}

function b64d(r) {
  var imgB64 = "R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///wAAACwAAAAAAQABAAACAkQBADs=";
  var bytes = Buffer.from(imgB64, 'base64');
  return r.return(200, bytes);

}
```

save this as gif.js

### NGINX Configuration

```
js_import gif from conf.d/gif.js;

server {
  listen 80;
  location / {
    add_header "Content-Type" "image/gif";
    js_content gif.b64d;
  }
}
```

This will return the GIF fully rendered.

```
$:/etc/nginx/conf.d# curl -s 127.1 --output test.gif && file test.gif
test.gif: GIF image data, version 89a, 1 x 1
```

With this you are able to decode and send any image you want.
Reference: https://nginx.org/en/docs/njs/reference.html#string

Comment: Very creative. Use case is purely research-based and experimental.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you suffer from a misconception about what *base64* is supposed to achieve in the first place. The purpose of encodings like *base64* is to inline arbitrary **binary data** into a **plain text** document. That's why you use base64 encodings to embed data into HTML or CSS.

However on the HTTP transport level, past the initial headers (which are plain text) the actual content is transferred as-is. You'd use base64 to embed the GIF into a HTTP header (where it'd sit rather useless, unless a HTTP client interprets it in some way).

The nginx `return` statement specifies the very content, that's sent right after the headers. And since the nginx configuration is a text file, it'd be a tough call to embed a GIF there. **BUT:** Although you can encode and place a GIF there in base64 perfectly well, which will transmitted just so, image/gif;base64 isn't a content type expected by a browser for regular HTTP. It's quite nonsensical; why bloat the transmission with an encoding where binary is just fine.

Technically it would be possible to patch nginx to decode the base64 on its end, but why go through all this effort?

The solution is simple: Just serve the file! Put your white pixel GIF as a file on your server, and in your location rule send out this one specific file. This is the most straightforward, least bandwidth consuming, most efficient way to do it.

**Update**

I think I should maybe elaborate, why serving out an on-disk file is the most efficient way to serve this pixel GIF:

Most operating systems *kernels* offer a syscall that allows to directly submit the contents of a file into a stream (pipe, socket, etc.); this syscall is usually called `sendfile`. Obviously nginx uses sendfile:

https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/master/src/os/unix/ngx_darwin_sendfile_chain.c

https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/master/src/os/unix/ngx_solaris_sendfilev_chain.c

https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/master/src/os/unix/ngx_freebsd_sendfile_chain.c

https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/master/src/os/unix/ngx_linux_sendfile_chain.c

Now it becomes important to understand how modern OSs allocate and manage memory: Ever since paging and swap memory was invented, to make life simpler, the memory allocations user space applications are working with are in fact cut from the storage I/O cache buffers (in case there's a swap partition/file this cache buffer is mapped to that swap partition, so when stuff needs to be paged out, all the management structures are already in place).

In short, when you read from a file, eventually things will go through this I/O cache, the "hot" parts of file will be cached there, without additional programmer effort. `sendfile` will simply send out those in-cache memory without invoking any file read-to-buffer write-from-buffer copy overhead. If it's a "hot" file, it will be sent out from there, with the in-memory copy already at hand. And if it's not resident, then the storage I/O will pull it directly into the socket send buffers.

Moreover, for a few years now, at least Linux and FreeBSD support socket level TLS (https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.6/networking/tls.html); this is nifty. If you got "standard" hardware, the TLS will be done in software (of course using the cryptographic instructions of the CPU if those are available). But there're network adapters that implement hardware TLS acceleration; and to reach that offload, you also go through the socket TLS layer. Using sendfile on that, will give you the shortest, most direct way for your GIF's data out to the network.

Now compare this with putting the GIF into your nginx configuration: The nginx-process has to hold that string somewhere in its memory. It's most likely not properly page aligned. When the request is made, that piece of memory must be wrapped up with the headers, then send to the socket, where a copy of that memory is made. The potential overhead is much larger.

Long story short: You want it to be efficient: Serve a file!

Comment: I did it, because in my experience a lot of people who encounter the use of base64 are oblivious for the actual reason this thing has been invented for in the first place. And by second order also, what this means for the actual use of it. You question was a good case in point. You gathered base64 as a means to include binary data into plain text documents; but you missed the finer point, why one would to include a binary blob into a text document in the first place. One uses base64 if the transport doesn't support binary natively (for example MIME email). HTTP deals with binary just fine.

Comment: I see. It sounds like you haven't had good experiences with others who use base64, is that what I'm hearing?

Comment: @AnthumChris: That's indeed the case. I've experienced the following: People who mistook base64 as some kind of encryption primitive (it is not). People who mistook base64 as a compression algorithm (it is not; in fact it will add 3/2 overhead). People who mistook base64 as some building block of some form of transfer optimization (it's not, it's an elaborate escaping scheme for binary data).

Comment: @AnthumChris: In your particular case, you've hit a mental barrier, which made you mix up the use of base64 to inline deliver binary data inside of HTML or CSS (for which the W3C standards provide URI schemes to support this), with a means to embed binary data inside of the nginx configuration file. However nginx doesn't "know" that this base64 encoded data is something that should be decoded before transmission and sent in binary form. And `…;base64` isn't a proper MIME type – browsers will interpret it as some unkown type at best, and are going to interpret it as plain text at worst.

Comment: Have you seen others hit these mental barriers often?

Comment: @AnthumChris: Yes. Let me ask you back: What exactly makes you think, that you absolutely, definitely must use base64 to implement whatever you're trying to do? And somewhat further: What is the motivation for you, to include some piece of playload data into the nginx configuration in the first place?